# Outlook breaking responsive template

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have built a mobile responsive email but on Outlook and Hotmail it ends up going into its mobile form rather than it's desktop form. So instead of having the image to the right of the text, it is put below the text.

I am not sure how to rectify this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
    table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

    /* RESET STYLES */
    img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
    body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
       color: inherit !important;
       text-decoration: none !important;
       font-size: inherit !important;
       font-family: inherit !important;
       font-weight: inherit !important;
       line-height: inherit !important;
    }



    /* MOBILE STYLES */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

     .img-max {
       width: 100% !important;
       max-width: 100% !important;
       height: auto !important;
     }

     .img-float {
            display:block;
            float:none;
            margin:0 auto 20px !important;
     }

     .max-width {
       max-width: 100% !important;
     }

     .mobile-wrapper {
       width: 85% !important;
       max-width: 85% !important;
     }

     .mobile-padding {
       padding-left: 5% !important;
       padding-right: 5% !important;
     }


     /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
     .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
     }

     .mobile-cell-hide {
         width: 0;
     }

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
 .mobile-show {
    display: none !important;
 }

}

    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
    div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
 <!--RIGHT ALIGNED IMAGE ARTICLE MODULE--->

                <tbody>

                    <tr>

                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 15px 0 15px;" class="section-padding"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>

            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="550">

            <tr>

            <td align="center" valign="top" width="550">

            <![endif]-->

                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 550px;" class="responsive-table">

                            <tbody>

                                <tr>

                                    <td>

                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:550px;" width="100%">

                                        <tbody>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td><!-- ARTICLE COPY -->

                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                                                    <tbody>

                                                        <tr>

                                                            <td align="left" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial,  sans-serif, serif; color: #000000; vertical-align:top" class="padding">

                                                            <div style="vertical-align: top">

                                                                <!--[if mso]>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="160" align="right" style="width:160px;"><tr><td style="padding:0 0 20px 20px;">

<![endif]--><a href="~PROBE(204)~"><img alt="insert alt text here" class="img-max img-float" align="right" style="display: block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #999999; vertical-align: top; Margin:0 0 10px 10px;" width="250px" src="http://hearst.emsecure.net/images/HouseBeautiful/spread1.jpg" /></a> <!--[if mso]>

</td></tr></table>

<![endif]-->

                                                            </div>

                                                            Dear ~FORENAME~,<br />

                                                            <br />

                                                            Every issue of <i>House Beautiful</i> is packed with the latest trends and stylish inspiration, featuring practical advice for your home and garden.<br />

                                                            <br />

                                                            To celebrate the bank holiday, we're offering you the chance to try six issues for <b>JUST &pound;6</b> and every month you'll be inspired by reader homes, beautiful buys and easy makeover ideas.<br />

                                                            &nbsp;</td>

                                                        </tr>

                                                    </tbody>

                                                </table>

                                                </td>

                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td align="center"></td>

                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>

                                    </td>

                                </tr>

                            </tbody>

                        </table>

                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>

            </td>

            </tr>

            </table>

            <![endif]--></td>

                    </tr>

                    <!--END OF RIGHT ALIGNED IMAGE ARTICLE MODULE--->
```

Comment: [This](https://www.outlook-apps.com/html-ignored-by-outlook/) will probably help. *"...– do not use external CSS files and do not define your CSS styles in the email HTML HEAD section. Use inline CSS;"*

Comment: It is not an external CSS and is within the head section

Comment: Many email clients do not support `<style>` tags at all. Technically speaking, they are not valid in `<body>`, even though most browsers support them.